# Appcelerator Keyboard Toolbar Doesn't hide in the simulator

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am using Appcelerator and the keyboard toolbar doesnt hide in the simulator, which causes all sorts of issues if i have a button at the bottom of the screen, it just permantly stays at the bottom.

Here is a video of the issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RypzFJwSbtw&feature=youtu.be

Here is my code.

```
<TextField class="setupPin" id="pinOne" keyboardType="Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_NUMBER_PAD" passwordMask="true" maxLength="4">
                <KeyboardToolbar>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Items>
                            <Button onClick="closeToolbar">button 1</Button>
                            <FlexSpace/>
                            <Button onClick="submitToolbar">button 2</Button>
                        </Items>
                    </Toolbar>
                </KeyboardToolbar>
            </TextField>
```

Can someone suggest a fix driving me crazy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to hide the toobar/keyboard from the toolbar buttons.  Add a comment if this doesn't work for you and I will look into it further.

https://gist.github.com/brentonhouse/2ffd923d41632d29bbd45c5516751d76

```
<Alloy>
   <TextField id="myTextField" width="Ti.UI.FILL" textAlign="Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT" keyboardType="Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_DECIMAL_PAD" verticalAlign="Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER" onFocus="showKeyboard">
      <KeyboardToolbar>
         <Toolbar>
            <Items>
               <Button systemButton="FLEXIBLE_SPACE" />
               <Button systemButton="DONE" onClick="hideKeyboard" textField="myTextField" />
            </Items>
         </Toolbar>
      </KeyboardToolbar>
   </TextField>
</Alloy>
```

---

```
var hideKeyboard = function(e) {
    var parent_name = e.source.textField;

    if(parent_name) {
        var parent = $[parent_name];
        parent.blur();
        parent.keyboardToolbar.visible = false;
    }

};

var showKeyboard = function(e) {
    e.source.keyboardToolbar.visible = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have implemented the function on ***button 1*** click to blur the ***pinOne*** field like this:

```
function closeToolbar() {
    $.pinOne.blur();
}
```

Assuming above implementation, now it is not a problem of your code, neither it is a problem in simulator, but there is another piece of feature in ios simulators that you can toggle the simulators keyboard.

There's an option to toggle in keyboard in simulators. See this [KEYBOARD SCREENSHOT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZdsEjK2ySIZ1B5RUIyN1FkQk0/view?usp=sharing).

Try toggling the keyboard after focusing on keyboard field, and make sure you have unchecked the **Connect Hardware Keyboard** option.

If **Connect Hardware Keyboard** is not checked, then you cannot use your physical keyboard to input, so to use physical keyboard and to hide the toolbar as well, play toggling **Toggle Software Keyboard** by keeping **Connect Hardware Keyboard** checked.